# Gradle way of handling maven non-lib artifact dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I previously archived a zip artifact in our internal Maven repository.

In my Gradle buildscript I can reference the artifact as a dependency and can get a path to the artifact, using:

```
configurations{
   resourceProperties
}

dependencies{
   resourceProperties "$group:$name:$version"
}

... def path = configurations.resourceProperties.asPath
```

Unfortunately I get all the zip artifact's project dependencies appended on the path as well.

Is there another Gradle way to handle non-lib Maven artifacts required in my build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a file or directory as a dependency.

Try to look at [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) starting from par 45.4

Comment: Thanks, that section was helpful.